# Use a pool to spawn images

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, threadpool, frames

Hi every one here is my code:

```
-(void) createNewImage {


[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

[views addObject:imageView];
[imageView release];

ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;
[XArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(240 - ix)/diviseurVitesse]];
[YArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(160 - iy)/diviseurVitesse]];
```

}

```
-(void)moveTheImage{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
    imageView = [views objectAtIndex:i];
    X = [[XArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    Y = [[YArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
imageView.center=CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
```

}
With this code, image are created and move to the center of the screen but after  some seconds the performance decrease and come to 30fps. I would like to keep fps at 60 but I don't know how to proceed.Some people say that I can use pool but it's hard for me to use it because I don't really know how to use it :/ sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely here - `[views addObject:imageView];`. Adding object to a persistent dataset like NSMutableArray retains the object, so memory consumption actually grows. Try manipulating your images in `[self.view subviews]` without storing them in array.

EDIT: Your code should look something like this

```
- (void)createAndMove {

UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
imageView.center = self.view.center;
}];

}
```

EDIT 2:

```
- (void)moveImages {
  for (UIImageView *img in [self.view subviews]) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    img.center = self.view.center;
  }];
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have to use an array because I want that multiple images move at the same time not  one, then another, then another...

Comment: So what? [self.view subviews] is NSArray too, you didn't know that? Or you just not using any native animation methods?

Comment: maybe I can use removeLastObject or removeObject:atIndex: or something like that ?

Comment: but how can I change my code to use  [self.view subviews] please ? :/

Comment: No, you should remove your image with `[myImage removeFromSuperview];` when your image should disappear. And don't use any other arrays.

Comment: yes I did [myImage removeFromSuperview]; but it's not my problem. the frames decrease in spite of this

Comment: with your code each image created move alone with my code images move together

Answer (score 0):

What happens when your object reaches the centre of the screen? If it just sits there and the other images overlap it, then you could then reset it to be at the start position rather than creating a new image. If you are moving them to the centre and then leaving them there, pretty soon you will have many many views and that will just kill the performance.

So, imagine you have 3 views. View 1 is created and appears at edge of screen and moves towards centre. When that is half-way to the centre, view 2 is created and appears at the edge of the screen and starts to move towards the centre. When view 2 is half-way to the centre, view 1 is at the centre and view 3 is created and appears at the edge of the screen. Now, when view 2 reaches the centre, view 1 is reset to be at the edge of the screen (it will be covered by view 2 so it won't be noticed). Then when view 3 reaches the centre, it will cover view 2, so that can be reset to the edge of the screen.

Hope this makes sense - it's a bit difficult without drawing pictures or knowing exactly what you are moving around on the screen, etc.

Comment: when my object reaches the centre of the screen I use removeFromSuperView is it good ?

Comment: To reset it, just change the position to the edge of the screen (the start position). Don't removeFromSuperView as you would just add it again anyway.

Comment: yes but when I change the position to the edge of the screen it keep moving in it's previous direction from the new center so it doesn't go to the center of the screen

Comment: Then you probably need to change your XArray and YArray entry too. I'm not sure why you have those. I'm struggling to understand exactly what you are trying to do - if you are trying to just move the images to the middle, then you seem to have much more code in there than is really necessary

Comment: so even if i use removeFromSuperview my fps will decrease ?

Comment: Yes, the fewer views you have for it to draw, the less the fps will go down. Just because you can't see it on the screen (because there is another image on top of it) doesn't mean it isn't taking time being drawn. If you want best performance for things like this, you are much better looking at something like cocos2d

Comment: I was told that cocos 2d is for lower class games.I don't know famous game that use cocos 2D .Do you ?

Comment: You aren't going to get any kind of performance from using UIViews for sprites. You need to do what Cocos2d does and render the graphics using openGL for performance. And who said it was for "lower class games" (and what does that even mean?)

Comment: I learned during one year how to do apps with UIView and now I have to learn another language it's hard for me. Many people say that opengl is very hard to understand .Which famous game use cocos 2D, because all cocos 2D games that I saw were bad quality games

Comment: Shouldn't really discuss so much here, but can't go to chat... cocos2D is just another library - you don't need to learn another language. cocos2D does all the openGL stuff for you. Who knows what games are written in cocos2d and just because you saw bad quality games doesn't mean it is cocos2d's fault. If you want game performance, you aren't going to get it with UIViews and similar.

Comment: a final question .I want to create an app using cocos 2D and I don't want people to see that I used cocos 2D is it possible ?

Comment: You mean remove the big "splash screen" with the cocos2d logo on it when your app launches? Yes, that's possible. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want people to see that you used it though...

Comment: Yes but if I remove the splash screen and the fps at the left bottom is it a way for people to know that I used Cocos 2D.Like for example  apple say next to my app :"this app used cocos 2D" ?